# How to change the name of the button? Ng-show, ng-if, ng-click does not work?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to change the name of the button from Hold Payment to Unhold Payment, it should first check the status of the checkstatus.is_holdpayment and then execute the function userhold_payment(). I tried various things, ng-show, ng-if but the name of the button does not change on click. On click it should go, Hold, Unhold, Hold, Unhold and also execute the same function, userhold_payment(). I want to change the name of the button using AngularJS. What is the mistake. Here is the main.html

```
<div ng-init="check_status()">
<button type="button"  ng-if="checkstatus.is_hold_payment" ng-click="userhold_payment();" class="btn-success btn-lg hold_payment_html" style="margin-top:7px; font-size:16px">Hold</button>
<button type="button" ng-if="!checkstatus.is_hold_payment" ng-click="userhold_payment();" class="btn-success btn-lg hold_payment_html" style="margin-top:7px; font-size:16px">UnHold</button>
</div>
```

Here is the Controller for the function.

```
$scope.userhold_payment = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/ngaffiliate/api/payment/change_hold_payment_status')
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('I called');
            $scope.userhold = response.data;
            console.log($scope.userhold.is_hold_payment);
        });
};

//this will call when ever your controller reinstance
($scope.check_status = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/ngaffiliate/api/payment/check_payment_status')
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('I called now')
            $scope.checkstatus = response.data;
            // console.log(response);
            console.log($scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment);
            if($scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment=="0")
                $scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment = true;


            else($scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment=="1")
                $scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment = false;
            $scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment =!$scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment;
                        console.log($scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment);



       });
})();
```

Comment: You're not changing the value of `$scope.checkstatus,is_hold_payment` in the function that gets called on click (`$scope.userhold_payment()`), so naturally the text doesn't change. Try calling `$scope.check_status()` inside your `$scope.userhold_payment()`.

And yeah, you should probably also remove the line Maciej Sikora told you to, since it would revert the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comment, you should probably call `$scope.check_status()` in your `$scope.userhold_payment()` function, since the function doesn't normally change the value of the `$scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment` variable. I also removed the line where you reversed the variable's value.

Plunker here to demonstrate: https://plnkr.co/edit/SWpdHGaNWIkyIWSvHyUU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
  <button type="button" ng-click="userhold_payment();" class="btn-success btn-lg hold_payment_html" style="margin-top:7px; font-size:16px">{{checkstatus.is_hold_payment ?? "Hold": "Unhold"}}</button>
```